# multiple countdown timer with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval, nuxt.js

I have an array of some people taking up a particular task, , each of them has a timer that ticks off the moment they pick the task, my problem is how to show the timer on the DOM, i sort of have a way to print it to the console already;

```
//in my methods: the time calc takes in two arguments to calculate the countdown

 },
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.singletask,
      loading: false,
      task: {},
      second: 1000,
      time: "Time Remaining:",
      minute: this.second * 60,
      hour: this.minute * 60,
      day: this.hour * 24,
      seconds: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      hours: 0,
      days: 0,
      image: "",
      centerDialogVisible: false,
      task_states: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async viewTask() {
      this.loading = true;
      try {
        let response = await this.$http.get("/task/" + this.id + "/show");
        console.log(response);
        this.task = response.data.data;
        console.log(this.task);
        this.task_states = response.data.data.task_states;
        this.task_states.forEach((task, i) => {
          task.obj = {};
        });
        console.log(this.task_states);
        // to calculate countdown for each taskState
        this.task_states.forEach((taskState, index) => {
          let countDown = new Date(taskState.end_date).getTime();
          let x = setInterval(() => {
            let now = new Date().getTime();
            let distance = countDown - now;

            let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            let hours = Math.floor(
              (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
            );
            let minutes = Math.floor(
              (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)
            );
            let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            // console.log(second, hour, day, minute);
            // return seconds, hours, days, minutes;
            taskState.obj.seconds = seconds;
            taskState.hours = hours;
            taskState.obj.days = days;
            taskState.obj.minutes = minutes;
            console.log(taskState.obj.seconds);

            //do something later when date is reached
            if (distance < 0) {
              clearInterval(x);
              this.time = "Time Ellapsed";
            }
          }, 1000);
          // this.task_states[index].obj = obj;
          // console.log(this.task_states);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      this.loading = false;
    },
```

in the HTML i have something like this

```
     <div class="d-flex" v-if="task_state.obj">
                          <h6>{{ time }}</h6>
                          <ul class="my-auto ml-1">
                            <li>
                              <span class="time" id="days">
                                <b>{{ task_state.obj.days }}</b> d
                              </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <span class="time" id="hours">
                                <b>{{ task_state.obj.hours }}</b> h
                              </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <span class="time" id="minutes">
                                <b>{{ task_state.obj.minutes }}</b> min
                              </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <span class="time" id="seconds">
                                <b>{{ task_state.obj.seconds}}</b> sec
                              </span>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

it successfully pribts to the console, but i don't know how to go about showing it on the DOM

Comment: you need to do something with `data`. Rather than assigning values locally i.e. `let seconds = ...` you should be doing `this.seconds = ...`

Comment: @DawoduFumbi please add complete script tag code.

Comment: @HardikShah refactored my code also, you can help me check it out, still not working, please i need your help

Comment: @A.Lau tried it but it was returning an empty string, i've refactored the code a little bit now, prints to to the console, but shows empty on the DOM

Comment: @DawoduFumbi  what is that `id` in data() anything related to route??
can you add complete code to code sandbox and share complete code here!!

Comment: @HardikShahnot It's a dynamic page i routed to, so i saved the ID to a variable to i can call it, data comes from my backend; not sure i know how to use sandbox in this situation but will try

Comment: @HardikShah https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-swanson-2lmow to the sandbox

Comment: thanks...but still did not understand how you taking id from the route and is your $http call working!!

Comment: @HardikShah yes It is, you can also drop an alternative method won't mind, but the countdown is more important cos i have a deadline to meet

Comment: @DawoduFumbi Do you want something like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp?

Comment: @hard yes which already works, the issue is, i want it for different individuals because it's a loop, so each individual has different countdowns

Comment: @DawoduFumbi I'm sorry but I'm still not understand what you are trying to display.. what response you getting from HTTP call...

Comment: @HardikShah i get a success call from it, 

this is my algorithm process

1. i make an http request
2. i save my response of task_states to a task_states variable;
3. I loop over task_states and create an empty object to contain the countdown values
4.Loop over the arrray again, get the end_date in in each object in the array, calculate the countdown and add it to the empty object earlier created
5. display it in the template

I hope this makes you understand it better

Comment: can you make an example on codesandbox?

Comment: @A.Lauhttps://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-swanson-2lmow

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you are doing it in the right way . you should try to get the whole remaining time in to seconds . and each second minus 1 from it. now you would have the whole remaining time in seconds right ? then you would show the time in the format you want with momentjs [here are the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)